# Access hdfs data from Matlab

Tags: matlab, hadoop, hdfs

we have installed Hadoop 2.5.1 on two Linux (Ubuntu) computers. One computer serves as a name node, the other one as a data node.

Now we want to access the data from a third computer, where Matlab 2014b is installed on a Windows operating system.

We have shared the folder of the Hadoop installation on our Ubuntu machine and set the HADOOP_PREFIX environment variable accordingly within Matlab on our Windows computer.

```
setenv('HADOOP_PREFIX','\\\myserverip\hadoop');
```

Now we create a datastore object according to the Matlab documentation:

```
file = 'hdfs://myserverip:portnumber/foldername/data.csv';
ds = datastore(file);
```

However, we always get the following error

```
Error using datastore (line 70)
Failure occured while trying to resolve path 'hdfs://myserverip:portnumber/foldername/data.csv'.
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: The same question is asked [here][1] and has an unaccepted response.


  [1]: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/158153-access-hdfs-from-matlab