# Reading files from HDFS in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, hadoop, hdfs

I'm trying to read folders from HDFS into my MATLAB application.

After setting env. vars (as described [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/read-from-hdfs.html) ) and using the MATLAB `datastore` function, I keep getting the following error:

> Failure occurred while trying to resolve path   'hdfs://myServer:9000/tmp/random.csv "

I tried the information provided in these two threads without luck:

- http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/158153-access-hdfs-from-matlab
- [Access hdfs data from Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337283/access-hdfs-data-from-matlab/36696051#36696051)

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: can you access the hdfs file on that address when you log into the cluster? It just seems that the error you post has a 'hdfs... followed by a " which is weird.

Comment: Hi, Yes. file is accessible on the cluster...

Comment: I don't use Matlab to access hdfs directly, I push hdfs results to a storage space (i.e. S3) and then access the storage space, I am not sure what could be causing the problem as I cannot see how your envs are set and how you are calling the datastore function, but assuming you have the same setup as the one in your links, I cannot see why it would fail.